# How can I disable the ENTER key on my textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, textarea

```
<form name='qform'>
<textarea name='q' rows='3' cols='60' wrap='hard' id='q' onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('clickit').click()"></textarea>
<input type='button' value='search' id='clickit' onclick="get();">
</form>
```

I have this form... it doesn't have a submit button because I am using jquery and under this form is a div area where the results will be shown. It is a search engine that does not have an input box but instead has a textarea. This is because it will be a multiple word searcher.

The problem is that if I press enter, the query is submitted and everything is ok ... but the focus on textarea goes down one line and that is a problem for me.

Basically I want the enter to have that one function only(submit) end nothing else.

Comment: You could just put the focus back on the textarea after the submit. But if the user clicks the "search" button, won't focus go to the button anyway?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable New Line in Textarea when Pressed ENTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779322/disable-new-line-in-textarea-when-pressed-enter)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the jquery function, use event.preventdefault and next do what you like.
For example

```
<script>
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
//Do your logic here
});
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 23):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('textarea').keypress(function(event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: [`keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). For standards compatibility, use [`event.key === "Enter"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#keys-whitespace) instead.

Answer (score 15):

Why not just use `<input type="text">` if you don't want multiple lines? You mentioned it will be a "multiple word searcher". Why does this require a `<textarea>`?

**Update**

Try this

```
$('textarea').bind('keypress', function(e) {
  if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: You might want to change the `return false;` to `e.preventDefault()`, just in case there are keypress bindings further up the DOM

Comment: Assuming you don't want those bindings, yes :)

Comment: REASON: I am sending text messages, they cannot have line breaks, yet at the same time I don't want the display of the text box to scroll to the right -- thus a textarea is appropriate.

Comment: @Andy Assuming you're talking about SMS, linebreaks would normally be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

})
```