# Disable New Line in Textarea when Pressed ENTER

Tags: textarea, newline, enter, shift

I am calling a function whenever someone press <kbd>enter</kbd> in the `textarea`. Now I want to disable `new line` or `break` when <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed.

So `new line` should work when <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed. In that case, the function **should not** be called.

Here is jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/bxAe2/14/

Answer (score 82):

try this

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){
// Enter was pressed without shift key
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
{
    // prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

update your fiddle to

```
$(".Post_Description_Text").keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
{
  // prevent default behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  //alert("ok");
  return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This answers the question. Keep in mind, that there are other ways to get a line break in your textarea, such as pasting or drag&drop. In this case you might want to also handle the change event, and replace the \r\n instead of preventing the event.

Comment: I can confirm that `.preventDefault()` works in plain JavaScript too.

Comment: @TalKohavy Jquery is a Javascript library is it not?  And as noted in the comments above *.preventDefault() works in plain JavaScript too*.  **Also if you look at his jsfiddle, it is written in Jquery.**

Comment: This answer deserves to a green tick

Answer (score 5):

Below code is to prevent to getting resize the "textarea", avoid scroll bar inside textarea, and also prevent to get into next line when enter key is pressed.

style.css

```
textarea {height:200px; width:200px;overflow:hidden;resize: none;}
```

index.html

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Script.js

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){
    // Enter pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        //method to prevent from default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes this worked for me but it also shows me keyCode is deprecated is there any alternative

Comment: if (e.key == "Enter")
    { 
       //your code 
    }

Answer (score 3):

**React: textarea w/ value and onChange event**

```
const PreventTextAreaEnter = () => {
   const [comment, setComment] = useState();

   const handleTextArea = (e) => {
      console.log({e}) // Destructure to get a more accurate log 

      // Return if user presses the enter key
      if(e.nativeEvent.inputType === "insertLineBreak") return;

      setComment(e.target.value);
   };

   return (
    <>
      <textarea value={comment} onChange={ (e) => { handleTextArea(e) } />
    </>
   )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That if statement what exactly what I was missing. Solved it for me.

Comment: In TypeScript I can not find inputType inside of naviteEvent.
My type is (e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>)

Comment: I would search the event obj to see if it's nested somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".Post_Description_Text").keypress(function(event) {

      if (event.which == 13) {        

        alert("Function is Called on Enter");

          event.preventDefault(); //Add this line to your code

       }

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Angular Users**

While there are existing working solutions, if anyone comes across this question using **Angular**, you can disable new lines with the following:

Add `<textarea ng-trim="false" ng-model='your.model' ...`

In your controller, add:

```
$scope.$watch('your.model', function(newvalue, oldvalue) {
    if (newvalue && newvalue.indexOf('\n') > -1) {
       $scope.your.model = oldvalue;
    }
});
```

Comment: This will throw your cursor to the end of your text

Answer (score -10):

use the `input` tag instead of `textArea` tag in your HTML

Comment: Inputs cannot break lines. CSS solutions are non standard. The only way is use a textarea for long inputs.