# How to trigger best_in_place events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I've looked all over Google and StackOverflow and looked through the best_in_place javascript code to no avail.

I am using best_in_place to edit a property of a `Post` model by using a textarea, like so:

```rb
<%= best_in_place @post, :summary, 
                 { :type => :textarea, :display_with => 'simple_format'}  %>
```

I want to be able to trigger best_in_place's submit function(s) when hitting Enter/Return unless it's pressed with the shift key (which would allow a carriage return), just as it would when clicking outside of the editable area. With a regular text/input, this is default functionality (minus the carriage return part). However when using textareas, it is not.

I've got a nice piece of jQuery pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779322/disable-new-line-in-textarea-when-pressed-enter) that handles identifying when Enter with/without shift is pressed, but I can't figure out how to trigger best_in_place to submit the data.

```js
//Have to bind it to the activate function, or else 
//the element won't be in the DOM when it tries to identify it
$('.best_in_place').bind('best_in_place:activate', function(){          
   $(this).find('textarea').keyup(function(e) {
      var $textarea = $(this);
      if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Don't make a new line         
        // This line does weird things
       $(this).parents('.best_in_place').trigger('best_in_place:update').trigger('best_in_place:deactivate');
      }
    });
});
```

I also have some functions bound to the `best_in_place:update` function, which basically add & remove classes for styling. With the above code, when I hit enter within a best_in_place textarea, the functions that I have bound to the `best_in_place:update` function fire, but no data is submitted to the server, as I can see in the console.

**TL;DR;** How can I trigger best_in_place to submit/update and deactivate on hitting the Enter key, just as it would when clicking outside the editable area?

Answer (score 0):

$('body').click();  maybe? Haven't used this framework but if there is no submit button and losing focus on the input submits the form, might work.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps triggering the blur event on the textarea. I believe that is where the deactivation stuff is happening.