# I have Copied Below code but its not working in my application. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

this code i have copied from here [Stack OverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779322/disable-new-line-in-textarea-when-pressed-enter) it is not working in my application BUT IT IS WORKING IN [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zala/so2cjo87/). It is not performing any action in Application.

```
<textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text"  class="Post_Description_Text"></textarea>

$(".Post_Description_Text").keydown(function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){ 
          e.preventDefault();return false;
     }   
});
```

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery library?

Comment: __not working is not a valid statement__. Check your browser console for any errors. Update your question if you have any

Comment: yes i have loaded jquery library and its working in jSFiddle.  issues are only in application