# How do I align text to the top in a resized <input type="text>?

Tags: html, css, forms

My code is currently
`<input type="text" style="height:100px;" placeholder="Content" required>`. The result that I get is a textbox with text in the middle. Is there a way to put the text on top?

Comment: Do you really need `input`? I think `textarea` is something you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input` content is always rendered in the middle. If you really want an `input` with text that stays in the top, consider using `textarea` and use `resize: none` CSS property to prevent users from resizing it. The `textarea` is content is aligned to the top unlike `input` when the height of the `textarea` is large i.e. `100px`.

**Note:** Textarea allows multi-line content so, you would need JavaScript to prevent the addition of multiple lines into the textarea. Perhaps, see [Disable New Line in Textarea when Pressed ENTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779322/disable-new-line-in-textarea-when-pressed-enter)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm pretty new to HTML, so I needed help finding an adequate solution.

Answer (score 1):

@joshiy390 I think you need Textarea instead of Input tag here
`<textarea style="height:100px;" placeholder="Content"></textarea>`. using Textarea have it's own advantages for such requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm pretty new to HTML, so I needed help finding an adequate solution.