# Prevent textarea from scrolling down when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a `<textarea>` for inputs. When a user presses 'enter', it automatically takes their input and runs a js function. However apart from running this function, it also takes the cursor to the next line. How do I made it so that the `textarea` has only one line or pressing enter simply doesn't do anything.

I tried adding the attribute `data-role = 'none'`.
I've even tried adding the CSS file

```css
.textarea{
   resize: none;
}
```

Nothing seems to be working. What should I try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent ENTER keypress to submit a web form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for, if i understand your question correctly.

```js
let t = document.getElementById("myTxt"); // grab the dom element

t.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => { // once any key is pressed
    if (e.keyCode === 13) { // if the key code is 13 (ENTER)
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent usual browser behavour
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="myTxt" cols="15" rows="1" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){
   // Enter was pressed without shift key
   if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
   {
       // prevent default behavior
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18779374/15136568

Comment: Credit to this same post??

Comment: Oh I pasted wrong URL, thank you for pointing out

Comment: Ah, well, it's a duplicate then :)

Comment: Please do not copy responses from other threads. Instead, refer to an existing answer with a comment or mark question as a duplicate.  [The FAQ does specifically state this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Answers that do not fundamentally answer (also duplicates of other answers) the question may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

In the js function that handles the event of the textarea you can add:       `e.preventDefault();`
(e is the name of the argument to this function).